# How to CONCAT Custom String ONLY into Column Names of Joined Table

Tags: sql-server

I have these two tables `company.tbl`:

| COMPANY_ID | COMPANY_NAME | COMPANY_CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |

and `foods.tbl`

| ITEM_ID | ITEM_NAME | ITEM_UNIT | COMPANY_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I need to add `_foo`, only to the end of all joined columns from `foods.tbl`

| COMPANY_ID | COMPANY_NAME | COMPANY_CITY | ITEM_ID_foo | ITEM_NAME_foo | ITEM_UNIT_foo | COMPANY_ID_foo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Can you please let me know how to achieve this?

```
SELECT *
FROM company
LEFT JOIN foods ON company.company_id = foods.company_id;
```

Comment: Instead of typing `*` type a specific column list and alias as desired, there is nothing automatic

Answer (score 0):

Try using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @CompanyColumns varchar(1000),
        @FoodColumns varchar(1000);

SELECT
    @CompanyColumns = STRING_AGG('c.' + column_name + ' as ' + column_name, ', ')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    table_name = 'company' AND
    table_schema = 'dbo';

SELECT
    @FoodColumns= STRING_AGG('f.' + column_name + ' as ' + column_name + '_foo', ', ')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    table_name = 'foods' AND
    table_schema = 'dbo';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = '
    SELECT
        ' + @CompanyColumns + ',
        ' + @FoodColumns + ' 
    FROM company c
        JOIN foods f ON 
            c.company_id = f.company_id;
'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```